# query execution is too long to load

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

can i minimize or shorter (if ever) this query? this query takes too long to load, how can I shorten the execution of this query? thanks.

this is my sql query:

```
$sql = "
  SELECT
    i.ID
  FROM item_tb i
  WHERE
    i.coID = '". $_SESSION['coID'] ."'
    AND i.isProduct = '1'
    AND i.isBom = '0'
    AND NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT
        s.ID
      FROM
        stocks_tb s
      WHERE
        i.ID = s.itemID
        AND s.brID = '". $brID ."'
   )
";
```

Comment: run `explain select ...` and see where no indexes are used.

Comment: ok i will do it now, tnx

Comment: Why dont you try with `JOIN` rather than `NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that your query converted `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT
  i.ID
FROM item_tb i LEFT JOIN stocks_tb s ON i.ID = s.itemID
WHERE
  i.coID = '". $_SESSION['coID'] ."'
  AND i.isProduct = '1'
  AND i.isBom = '0'
  AND s.brID = '".$brId."'
  AND s.itemID IS NULL;
```

and this is faster than your query.

Comment: hey dude, thanks for the reply. I tried your query but it doesn't return any record. my query is actually trying to fetch all records from item_tb that does not exist in stocks_tb. it works but the execution is too long.

Comment: @AdrianC. humm. Can you post your schema & data at sqlFiddle? I have test in my MySQL, created two table (tbl1, tbl2) and searched all rows from tbl1 not in tbl2 using LEFT JOIN. but it worked.

Comment: @AdrianC. Here is what i had tested. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d12344/1/0 sorry if i misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

You use many AND operator... Use bracket within the AND condition.. That's it

Comment: Please expand your answer. What do you mean exactly and how it will help the OP's query run faster.

Comment: your query should be need to look like this                                     SELECT meta_name, meta_value
FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE 
(meta_name = 'last_name' AND meta_value LIKE  '%mahajan%' )
  OR
(meta_name = 'first_name' AND meta_value LIKE  '%a%');